# Linq, filter out multiples

Tags: c#, linq

I have written a Search-function in my MVC-project, it matches a database.

The database have the struct like this:

Name - string (The name of the data)

SubName - string (the subname of the data)

SomeData - int (the actual data)

So if i have like 100 posts with a name and a specific subname with different values for the data. and then 100 posts more with the same name but a different subname.

Now when i search the database i use this linq-code;

```
        var names = db.Graphs
            .Where(r => r.Name.Contains(term))
            .Take(5).Distinct()
            .Select(r=> new {label = r.Name});
```

I thougth that that maby would get med 5 distinct answers, but it dosent...

I get five of the first 100 post, i would like to filter so that i take only uniqe name with subnames. So in the example above i would have revived 2 entrys.

Feel like i have tried everything and failed so any input would be appriciated.

Comment: Have you tried using Distinct? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx

Comment: The query has nothing to do with the database structure you showed at the beginning of your question. Furthermore, you didn't show any sample data so it is not clear why the sample query should return 2 entries (and not 1 or 4).

Comment: _"Feel like i have tried everything"_ But you haven't shown what you've tried.

Comment: No, thats correct, i do not filter on subname. Thats because i have not got it to work so i thought that it was best to post code that i knew worked as intended. I have tried the distinct but im not sure how to really use it

Comment: I update my post with the post so you can see what i have tried. :)

Comment: What does distinc do, if i use it as the example above i dont see any change.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var names = db.Graphs
    .Where(r => r.Name.Contains(term))
    .GroupBy(s=>s.Name).Take(5)
    .Select(r => new { label = r.FirstOrDefault().Name });
```

You should apply Distinct()  before Take().I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I really dont know what i do wrong but i dont get it to return even multiples of Name.

Comment: Hi I have updated the solution please try it. I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems like the GroupBy sort everything out... I dont get it to compute. Thans alot for your help. :)